# Python Gobject broken Help?

Tags: gnome, 16.04, python, libraries, gobject

I don't know what broke it, but my python Gobject library is missing something ... 
When I try to run most tools like 
gnome-tweak-tool
which require GTK, I get an error saying :

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "/usr/bin/gnome-tweak-tool",
>   line 24, in 
>       gi.require_version("Gtk", "3.0") AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'require_version'

I tried to reinstall python-gobject, for python 2 and 3, install from the source the latest version etc etc. 
What am I missing !!! I feel like some library is missing which is optional and it causes this ?

help !

Comment: what did you exactly (re) install `python-gobject` or `python-gi`? I suspect `python3-gi` is the one to try.

Comment: Hi @Xqua, did you try?

Comment: python3-gi is already the newest version (3.20.0-0ubuntu1).

Comment: your gtk might be broken